# Need data on disk drive management by OS: getting base I/O unit size, “sync” option, Direct Memory Access

Tags: linux, hard-drive, database, io

I want to ensure I have done all I can to configure a system's disks for serious database use. The three areas I know of (any others?) to be concerned about are:

1. **I/O size:** The database engine and disk's native size should either match, or the database's native I/O size should be a multiple of the disk's native I/O size.
2. **DMA:** Disks that are capable of Direct Memory Access (eg. IDE) should be configured for it.
3. **Write-caching:** When a disk says it has written data persistently, it must be so! No keeping it in cache and lying about it.

I have been looking for information on how to ensure these are so for CentOS and Ubuntu, but can't seem to find anything at all.

I want to be able to check these things and change them if needed.

Any and all input appreciated.

**Please note:** The actual hardware involved is *very* modest. The point is to get the most out of what hardware we do have, even though it's "not very serious hardware" from a broader perspective.

Comment: Are you looking for an utility to check/set those parameters or a list of which parameters you should check?

Comment: For #3, don't you want to *disable* write caching so it forces the HDD buffer to be flushed to disk (instead of allowing it to write whenever it wants)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use, e.g., `hdparm -d -W /dev/hda` to get/set the DMA and write-caching values for an IDE drive.

Replace *hda* with *sda* for a SATA/SCSI drive